# (python) Spark .textFile(s3://...) access denied 403 with valid credentials

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, http-status-code-403, access-keys

In order to access my S3 bucket i have exported my creds

```
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
export AWS_ACCESSS_ACCESS_KEY=
```

I can verify that everything works by doing

```
aws s3 ls mybucket
```

I can also verify with boto3 that it works in python

```
resource = boto3.resource("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
resource.Object("mybucket", "text/text.py") \
            .put(Body=open("text.py", "rb"),ContentType="text/x-py")
```

This works and I can see the file in the bucket.

However when I do this with spark:

```
spark_context = SparkContext()
sql_context = SQLContext(spark_context)
spark_context.textFile("s3://mybucket/my/path/*)
```

I get a nice

```
> Caused by: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Service Error
> Message. -- ResponseCode: 403, ResponseStatus: Forbidden, XML Error
> Message: <?xml version="1.0"
> encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The
> AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our
> records.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>[MY_ACCESS_KEY]</AWSAccessKeyId><RequestId>XXXXX</RequestId><HostId>xxxxxxx</HostId></Error>
```

this is how I submit the job locally

spark-submit --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.98,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 test.py

Why does it works with command line + boto3 but spark is chocking ?

EDIT:

Same issue using s3a:// with

```
hadoopConf = spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "xxxx")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "xxxxxxx")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
```

and same issue using aws-sdk 1.7.4 and hadoop 2.7.2

Comment: read this? https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/spark_s3.html

Comment: I think that it would also work with exporting the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY. is create that credentials file really a necessity? as you can see Spark correctly picks up the AWS_ACCESS_KEY from the env variable but for reason fails to authenticate ?

Comment: Spark is distributed. Because you have ENV variables in one executor doesn't mean the other executors have it as well. You should use `SparkConf` to set the values

Comment: getting the same error with
hadoopConf = spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "xxxxx")
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "xxxxxx)
and same error when setting them with SparkConf

Comment: @cricket_007I think I found the issue I have created a new post for it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669246/spark-is-inventing-his-own-aws-secretkey

Answer (score 7):

Spark will automatically copy your AWS Credentials to the s3n and s3a secrets. Apache Spark releases don't touch the s3:// URLs, as in Apache Hadoop, the s3:// schema is associated with the original, now deprecated s3 client, one which is incompatible with everything else.

On Amazon EMR, s3:// is bound to amazon EMR S3; EC2 VMs will provide the secrets for executors automatically. So I don't think it bothers with the env var propagation mechanism. It might also be that how it sets up the authentication chain, you can't override the EC2/IAM data.

If you are trying to talk to S3 and *you are not running in an EMR VM*, then presumably you are using Apache Spark with the Apache Hadoop JARs, not the EMR versions. In that world use URLs with s3a:// to get the latest S3 client library

If that doesn't work, look at the troubleshooting section of [the apache docs](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/index.md). There's a section on "403" there including recommended steps for troubleshooting. It can be due to classpath/JVM version problems as well as credential issues, even clock-skew between client and AWS.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it in the originap post but I'm not running this in an EMR (it works in there). I'm running it locally. I will try with s3a://

Comment: Same thing but the error slighly  different:
Error Message: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: XXXX, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden

Comment: OK, well S3A is the ASF code. As well as an auth problem, it can suffer from an incompatibility between joda-time and the JVM version. I'll edit my answer with a link to the relevant docs

Comment: Thanks for the link. My clock is at the right time, I use java 7 and as specified in the original post my creds are correct because both aws s3 command like and boto3 CAN read the bucket without any problem

Comment: @Seteve I think I found the issue, I have create a new post for it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669246/spark-is-inventing-his-own-aws-secretkey

Comment: saw that. I think it's EMR related. Try putting the secrets in the URL as a final experiment, remembering to escape the + and / symbols, and remembering never to share the secret with anyone else

Comment: Im not running anything in EMR....... this is all locally. I have tried as well the url one but spark is still magically generating a random secret_key instead of reading the one I provide